# Copy information of GoogleMaps another activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to make an app using GoogleMaps API. Mainly I have two activity.

This is my Main Activity. 
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/6enoF.png

Map in this activity is not changeable. When I click draw route button, I go to my other activity MapsActivity. And I pick a pin and draw a route.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDuIa.png

Now when I click ok button, I want to copy the map with route from MapsActivity to MainActivity.

I tried some stuff but I can't do it. Can you help me? Thanks :)

This is my [MapsActivity](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11913092/)

And this is my [MainActivity](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11913095/)

Comment: Try to paste your code and images here itself. Links may expire

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya i used many times this site and i didn't face any problem. But thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you try to do is starting a second Activity from your MainActivity because you want to get a result from it (the result are the Waypoints of your route).

To do this Android provides the standard functionality `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()`.

For detailed information have a look at: 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: not exactly. i try to when i click button from MapsActivity. I try to show my map from MapsActivity to MainActivity

Comment: Yes, but you do not hand the MapView to the MainActiviy but the waypoints (and maybe the map extend). And that waypoints will be added to the MapView in your MainActivity (and if you want you set the same extend like the user set to the MapViee in the MapActivity).

Comment: ok i got it by the way how can i transfer the camera position between activities. Do you know it?

Comment: Use map.getCameraPosition() to get the properties you need like center coordinates and zoom level.